# Getting Java Collections Binary Search to return multiple values

Tags: java, collections, binary-search

I am wondering if there is any way to get the Binary Search in Java to return multiple instances of a value.  For example, I have an ArrayList of Items of which one field is a String array of keywords.  Is there a quicker way than a linear search using the contains() method to retrieve items by keyword and store them in a separate collection?  Or by a String such as Author?

```
...Item...
private String[] keywords;
private String author;
...
```

Comment: Could you be more precise? Multiple values in one call... You might need to write a wrapper which stores the output in an array and returns it.

Comment: Either in one call, or I suppose using multiple calls and some sort of returned flag?

Comment: make the question more clear please

Answer (score 5):

You almost certainly want to have different views on the same collection. For example, you could have:

- A `List<Book>` of all items
- A `Multimap<String, Book>` for "by author" lookup
- A `Multimap<String, Book>` for "by keyword" lookup (where the same book can appear in multiple entries)

If I were writing this, `Multimap` would probably be an implementation in [Guava](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com), but others are available too.

Of course, that's assuming you really *want* to avoid a linear scan. How much does your code need to scale?

Comment: Ok, that's what I thought and what I was trying to avoid.  I just wasn't sure if there was a workaround.  Thank you

Comment: @Jon You sure get up early on a Sunday. ;)

Comment: @PeterLawrey: I have children, and my wife is on Guide camp :)

Comment: lol. Exactly what I was thinking. My youngest is 4.5 yo. I guess yours is slightly younger. ;)

Comment: @PeterLawrey: Nope, mine are 8, 6 and 6... but they still get up at 7am.

Comment: I taught mine not to wake me, ... until they are hungry ... :)

Comment: @PeterLawrey - wait until they are teenagers ... and you won't be able to get the out of bed :-)

Comment: @StephenC Oh yes, my oldest is 14. ;)

Answer (score 2):

While I'd strongly encourage JonSkeet's suggestion, once you have the result from a binary search, you could explore backwards & forwards from the resulting index, looking for values that no longer support your criteria, just a suggestion ;)

Comment: That's what I'm gonna do, too. I have a sorted collection of entries in a bilingual dictionary, and there are duplicate headwords.

Answer (score 0):

I don't fully understand your question, but you can pass a complex, custom Comparator to binarySearch to handle some of these tricky cases.